# JS - localeCompare is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
const test = "true";
console.log(test.localeCompare("true", undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }));
```

And what i get in my console is `0`. Shouldn't it be `1`?

Comment: Why would you expect `1`?

Comment: IF it's the same it returns 0. Try it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: Oh oops, returning `1` made more sense to me if the result was `true`.

Comment: @Gambit2007 Don't think of it as returning a "yes" or "no", but rather a "before", "same", or "after" (`-1`, `0`, `1`). This is common with sort functions as well.

Comment: Ok didn't realize it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the JavaScript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

- Negative when the referenceStr occurs before compareStr
- Positive when the referenceStr occurs after compareStr
- Returns 0 if they are equivalent

I would say "true" and "true" are equivalent. And in case that is the source of the confusion, when they say 'after' they are talking about the sort order, not the declaration.